# How should I encapsulate my MVC-Action in order to avoid code duplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, encapsulation, code-duplication

I have two classes - MVC-Controlles in this particular case – that have one common controller action (a JSON action that will be called from JavaScript). Because of code duplication, I would like to put this action in a parent controller class. We already have a controller base class that inherits from Controller and is used as base class, with common functionality, from 6 other Controllers. My JSON action is actually common only for 2 controllers, so I think that it’s not a good idea to put my JSON action in the base controller that is already used by the other 6 controllers. Here’s the existing class hierarchy graph:

[Existing Controller class hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koz8S.png)

**Where should I put my JSON action in order to avoid code duplication?** My idea is to inherit the class ControllerBase – let’s say ControllerBaseExtended – and to place my JSON action in here. So now, my 2 Controllers can inherit from ControllerBaseExtended instead of ControllerBase. This is how the class hierarchy would look like at the end:

[Final Controller class hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axRhR.png)

**Is there any better way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating another base controller, extract code from both actions into another class, e.g. JsonActionProcessor. Then you will need to call that implementation.

```
public class JsonActionHelper
{
    public JsonResult Something()
    {
        //do something common
        return new JsonResult();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from your actions

```
public JsonResult Action1()
{
    return new JsonActionHelper().Something();
}

public JsonResult Action2()
{
    return new JsonActionHelper().Something();
}
```

If you have UnitTests then you should extract interface from JsonActionHelper and inject it into your Controllers.

However if you have 2 identical actions, why just not to have one action and call it via JavaScript from different views?

Comment: I think I will try to use this composition solution instead of inheritance. The action is the same for both controlles, but the result of the action is coming   from a Service object. This Service object is controller specific. So I think the problem moves down to the service/repository layer now.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your controllers to inherit BaseController instead of Controller.

**It sounds like you are already doing this**.... but for some reason its not good, could you explain a little better as to why this is not working for you...

```
public class [my]Controller : BaseController
{
    public ResualtAction [my]Action 
        return Base.Something();
    }
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public CustomeReturnAction Something()
    {
        return new CustomeReturnAction();
    }
}
```

or is it that your just trying to organize it better....

if that is the case then just move all the return action types into another class and let your BaseController inherit from that, I think your saying that already, if you are then yes that is good.

Comment: I am just trying to organize my source code better and learn how others are solving this problem. I somehow didn't want to inherit the custom base controller but I didn't know how to solve the problem in another way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality of the duplicate code. You can use anything from inheritance or composition (with an injected class) to reuse code in different controllers.

For instance: we have a Calculation class for calculating the prices of products and use Dependancy Injection to inject this logic into different controllers. The controller then uses this Calculator to present the output.

Maybe look into dependancy injection with ASP.Net MVC. I recommend [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html). It integrates nicely into the ASP.Net MVC framework.